# Most efficient way to group records alphabetically with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a rolodex-style grouping with a large list of contacts with LINQ & Entity Framework.

I have a `Contacts` model, which needs to be wrapped in a `GroupedContacts` model, which contains a `Initial` property. I'd like, where a record exists for the letter, the initial property to be filled and the `Contacts` list within to be populated:-

```
public char Initial { get; set; }
public List<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
```

Can anyone lend me their zen levels of LINQ to achieve this please?

For completeness, my contacts `get` currently looks like this:-

```
using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
            {
                var contacts = from c in ctx.Contacts
                               where c.ClientId == clientid
                               select c;
                return contacts.ToList();
            }
```

Help, as always, is appreciated :)

**EDIT**

I re-read my question a few times and feel it's a little vague.  To clarify, I'm trying to create data like so:-

```
{
        initial: 'c',
        contacts: [
            {
                name: 'Charlie Chaplin',
                primaryContact: {
                    type: 'phone',
                    value: '0123456789'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Charlie Sheen',
                primaryContact: {
                    type: 'email',
                    value: 'sheen@charliepower.com'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Colin Caterpiller',
                primaryContact: {
                    type: 'email',
                    value: 'colin@caterpiller.com'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Explain your `Contacts` class. By which property you want to group?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, please see latest edit - this may explain a little more ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works:

```
contacts
.GroupBy(c=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Name) ? '' : c.Name[0])
.Select(g=>new GroupedContacts {Initial = g.Key, Contacts = g.ToList()});
```

That will group by the first character of the `Name` property (or an empty string if `Name` is empty or `null`) and return the grouping key as the `Initial` and the list of contacts in that group as the `Contacts`.

Comment: +1 but I think OP needs GroupedContacts object instead of anonymous one

Comment: +1 excellent, quick response. let me try it out and i'll post back/mark as answer as necessary. thanks guys ;)